# Configuring of Outlook with Powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am trying to write a script which does few basic steps for starting outlook and logging in. I have looked around but did not find anything related to this. Mostly all post were about access the outlook to email and other things.

I have attached few screenshots to describe the steps which I want to script.
Is this something possible from power shell? or either from command line

All other outlook configuration is done. Just user logging steps needs to be done.

[Steps for configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoTXw.jpg)

[Logging into outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkBjx.jpg)

Comment: You probably want to use a MSP or PRF file to do this. Check out [this link](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/deployprf.htm) for more info on that.

Comment: If your computers are domain joined you can use Group Policy to configure all of these settings automatically. The user just runs Outlook and silently setup the profile and configure the server settings for them. It's even easier if you're using Exchange too.

Comment: @JamesC. Yes, computers are in domain and exchange is being used. Right now what I know is, outlook server setting are configured and outlook is installed on work-spaces. I am trying to configure user logging into outlook settings. As you mentioned its easier if exchange is being used, could you please explain more about this. I am totally a beginner when it comes to outlook/exchange. Thanks

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Thanks for sharing that link. It is really helpful. So far deploying msp-file looks like a good solution.

Comment: Group Policy questions are better suited to http://serverfault.com as they aren't programming related so aren't discussed here. Basically you setup a single group of settings apply them to your users and the Outlook Profile and Server configuration will be done. If you've not used Group Policy before you're missing out on one of the most useful features of having a domain!